# bootstrap input-group-addon need to use with button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Check the bootstrap code bellow. The  is attached with input text field which looks like button however  should be a button to submit form data. Please tell me how can i implement button to submit from data also it will display just beside input like now?

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="eg: restaurant templates">

                <span class="input-group-addon btn btn-primary">Search</span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: sounds kind of demanding ... please tell me ... There are several ways to do what you ask  ... but lets just say there may be *magic* in play .... (search for jquery and attach an action to your element)

Comment: any easiest way? i want to make it with easy way without any js or css if possible

Comment: Style your button with the same classes as your span, maybe? ;)

Comment: if i remove span then position of button not stays on input next. Its just come to bottom of input then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="eg: restaurant templates">
        <input type="submit" value="Search" class="input-group-addon btn btn-primary">
    </div>
</div>
```

Not that hard. It's a matter of playing the values

For reference:
https://www.bootply.com/CsQwZjay9w

Comment: https://ibb.co/bKZzp6 but your code looks like that

Comment: @Kevinhimch Is that pic your site? Cause you may have CSS code that may interfear then. If you look at the bootply, you see it shows correct